# WP - trying to use `wp_dropdown_users( )` as custom user profile field

Tags: php, wordpress, drop-down-menu

I have update to my user profile page to include several select fields with no problem, but I'm not sure how to parse `wp_dropdown_users( )` in a way that I can save the selected value to the profile.

Currently I have this as my markup:

```
<tr>
    <th>
        <label for="user"><?php _e('Select associated user', 'mv'); ?></label>
    </th>
    <td>
        <?phpwp_dropdown_users(); ?><br />
        <span class="description"><?php _e('Please enter the ADOC\'s name.', 'mv'); ?></span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

and I'm trying to save it like so:

```
function save_custom_userprofile_fields( $user_id ) {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) )
    return FALSE;
    update_usermeta( $user_id, 'user', $_POST['user'] );
}
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_custom_userprofile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_custom_userprofile_fields' );
```

The markup gives me the select, but when I try to save the profile, that select reverts back to the value of the first option.

Any help or guidance on this is, as always, greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first of all the function you are using to save the field is deprecated.

**See:** https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_usermeta/

Otherwise, you are doing it right. You only need to retrieve the saved value and supply it as `selected` parameter to `wp_dropdown_users` function.

So something like this will do,

**Code for Showing Field**

```
function new_user_profile_fields( $user ) 
{ 
    $selected = get_user_meta( $user->ID, '_custom_dropdown_user', true );

    ?><tr>
        <th>
            <label for="user"><?php _e('Select associated user', 'mv'); ?></label>
        </th>
        <td>
            <?php wp_dropdown_users( array( "selected" => $selected ) ); ?><br />
            <span class="description"><?php _e('Please enter the ADOC\'s name.', 'mv'); ?></span>
        </td>
    </tr><?php 
}
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'new_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'new_user_profile_fields' );
```

**Code for Saving Field**

```
function save_new_user_profile_fields( $user_id ) 
{
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) ) { 
        return false; 
    }

    update_user_meta( $user_id, '_custom_dropdown_user', $_POST['user'] );
}
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_new_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_new_user_profile_fields' );
```

Comment: Thanks @Shazyriver, good to know about `update_user_meta`, but it doesn't change anything. When I do this, the dropdown works, but no value gets saved for that field. As soon as you hit save changes and the page refreshes and that dropdown value reverts back to the default value.

Comment: I changed the boolean in the `$selected` variable to `true` and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: My bad, forgot to change it to true. Glad you worked it out though. Have edited my answer now.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to pass the saved meta_value of "user" to the wp_dropdown_users function. This should be passed in the $args parameter like so:

```
wp_dropdown_users(array(
    'selected' => get_usermeta( $user_id, 'user', true)
));
```

You can see more on the wordpress reference:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dropdown_users/